# How to hide my ip adress in "received" header when I send emails from my machine via Google smtp?

Tags: header, smtp, nodemailer

I successfully set up sending emails with nodemailer using Google Workspace SMTP.

Now i have a question: is it possible to hide my IP address in the headers (Received: from) when I send emails from my machine via Google smtp?

Perhaps the mailauth utility somehow help me in solving this issue?

https://nodemailer.com/extras/
Thank you

Received: from [127.0.0.1] ([my_ip_address])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This header field is under Google's control, not yours. I'm not aware of any ESMTP extension to ask the recipient not to disclose your IP address. Your best option is to notify Google that disclosing personal information, such as your IP address, to third parties without your explicit consent violates many privacy laws, such as GDPR.